# What is the simplest way to show datetime only till minutes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime

I have a input field of type "datetime-local" . When I am assigning to it the current TimeStamp, the input filed is showing the seconds and milliseconds also. What is the simplest way to show the time only till minutes ?

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="DateTime" ng-model="formInfo.dateTime">  
  </body>
```

The app.js is :

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.formInfo = {};
   $scope.formInfo.dateTime = new Date();
});
```

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/68XAbgvtz0kZHHeg4ILi)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: why you not use **date** filter see this plunker
https://plnkr.co/edit/dVabveNfS8ehyTAOQLMu?p=preview

Comment: @Sandeep, Thanks for information but I want the time also and that too only till minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using date filter as suggested by Sandeep in the comments :

```
  <body  ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="DateTime" placeholder="Enter the date and time of consumption" ng-model="formInfo.dateTime| date:'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm'">
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are using the browser implemented datetime picker.  Seeing as this isn't standard across browsers, without using another or having a consistent api for datetime pickers, As far as I know, the datetime input types don't have any options at all associated with them.  Below is how you can format a Date() type easily though as I posted it before I noticed you were talking about the display of the browser implemented datetime picker.

**Format historical reference**

toString().split().slice().join();

This likely isn't as efficient as just formatting it using some of the functions it provides.  Its pretty simple though.

```js
var a = (new Date()).toString().split(" ").slice(0,5).join(" ");

document.write(a);
```

Comment: But we will not be able to simply assign  `$scope.formInfo.dateTime = a`

Comment: ah yeah... really just display of input is what he wants changed =/...  Not sure you can do that considering the datepicker is implemented by the browser used.

Answer (score 0):

try using http://momentjs.com/ to formate your model content.

or if you are using angular datepicker
https://github.com/g00fy-/angular-datepicker

you already has a directive for formatting date.

```
<input type="datetime" format="dd MMM yyyy" >
```